# BindingSource.DataSource = MyDataTable; Changes Current 3 times

Tags: c#, datatable, datasource, bindingsource

```
Windows.Forms.BindingSource.DataSource bs = new DataSource();

bs.CurrentChanged += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Changed!"); }

Data.DataTable MyDataTable = SQL.Select("...");

Windows.Forms.BindingSource.DataSource = MyDataTable;
```

and result is:
Changed!
Changed!
Changed!

Comment: What's the call stack for each one? (print `Environment.StackTrace`)

Answer (score 1):

The [CurrentChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.currentchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) can be called through various actions:

> The CurrentChanged event is raised whenever the Current property changes for any of the following reasons:
>
> - The current position of the List changes.
> - The DataSource or DataMember properties change.
> - The membership of the underlying List changes, which causes Position to refer to a different item. Examples include adding or deleting an item before the current item, deleting or moving the current item itself, or moving an item to the current position.
> - The underlying list is refreshed by a new sorting or filtering operation.

When you are attaching the DataTable to the BindingSource.DataSource property, it is most likely hitting several of those points (initial, cursor position, etc).

The quick work-around is to wire the event after setting the DataSource (your posted code doesn't compile, btw):

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = SQL.Select("...");
bs.CurrentChanged += delegate { Console.WriteLine("Changed!"); };
```